# Move-attack order and unspent movement - can I mix these however I want?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions

This is possibly a very simple question, but I couldn't find a definitive answer in the players handbook.

If a character has a speed of 6, can he move 3 squares, perform an action, then move the remaining 3 squares?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No, a standard action cannot bisect a move action.

Each action must be fully resolved before you can begin another action (aside from triggered actions). However, you can use them in any *order* you like: attack, then move; or move before attacking. There are specific powers and features which provide exceptions to this rule.

Comment: free actions are also an exception here IIRC.

Comment: What if you ready an action (standard attack) with a trigger of "When I become adjacent to an enemy" or something like that?

Comment: @jbabey That would be a triggered action treated as an immediate reaction, and so takes place right after the action which triggered it; it cannot interrupt that action (also by the definition of "readied action" it can't happen on your turn anyway).